# ionic native HTTP call with content-type text/plan?

Tags: javascript, angular, http, ionic-framework, ionic3

I am trying to make a HTTP call and my Content-Type is text/plan but I am working with ionic-native/http which only take object and array,here is what I have tried

Error: advanced-http: "data" argument supports only following data types: Array, Object

```
TestIR(item){

  let headers = { 'Content-Type': 'text/plain'}; 
  let sender ='sendir,1:1,0,';
  let code = item.keys[10].code;
  let body = sender+code;
  let url= "http://10.75.0.120/v2/CI00e0148a";

  this.httpNative.setDataSerializer( "json" );
  this.httpNative.post(url,body,headers).then(val=> 
   {console.log(val)}).
  catch(e=>{console.log(e)})

}
```

Comment: What happens when you comment out this line => `this.httpNative.setDataSerializer( "json" );` ?

Comment: Shouldn't content-Type be written  as `'text/plain'` not `plan`, if that is the type, which you want.

Comment: still I get the same error

Comment: I changed it to plain but still i am getting the same error @Geshode

Comment: you are setting the serializer to `'json` and i am guessing your `body` cannot be converted to json as it is not an array. did you try changing the serializer to the `utf8` option? or just creating a simple array to include your body and pass it to httpNative?

Answer (score 7):

Assumption: The HTTP plugin being used is [cordova-plugin-advanced-http](https://github.com/silkimen/cordova-plugin-advanced-http), linked from the Ionic Docs.

### Setting the Data Serializer to json tells the plugin to expect a javascript object, but the body you are sending is a string

### Solution 1

If the API you are sending data to can handle it, set the Data Serializer to `"utf8"`.

```
this.httpNative.setDataSerializer( "utf8" );
```

This tells the plugin to expect text.

### Solution 2

Change the body to an object before calling POST.

```
body = JSON.parse(json);
```

The string you pass to `JSON.parse()` must be valid json.

Edit : Removed references to a bug that is now fixed

Answer (score 0):

If you are using the [`cordova-plugin-advanced-http`](https://github.com/silkimen/cordova-plugin-advanced-http)  you could also do the following if you only want to set the content type for one request.

```
const options: any = {
    serializer: 'utf8',
    method: 'post',
    data: 'my string value' 
};
this.http.sendRequest('https://mysite', options);
```

If your response type is `json` I recommend to parse it by yourself by using `JSON.parse`.

Answer (score 0):

I was receiving the same error and I tried the @Glen Davies solution, but the error kept and was intermittently.
Sometimes it used to work, sometimes not.

`Error: advanced-http: "data" argument supports only following data types: Array, Object`

I'm using Ionic 3 application with cordova http plugin in the `http-interceptor` and after some hours, I've discovered the problem was that even with the serializer being set in the `app.component.ts`, it was not working.

The solution was moving the:

```
this.http.setSSLCertMode('pinned');
this.http.setDataSerializer('utf8');
```

To the constructor inside the `HttpInterceptor`.

After this, the error was gone.